# Let's get critical: Nov 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Salesforce Stack Exchange](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Generic Apex Trigger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17527/generic-apex-trigger)

  **Net Score: 18** (Excellent: 18, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING error when Approval Process set to Manually Select](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17596/required-field-missing-error-when-approval-process-set-to-manually-select)

  **Net Score: 15** (Excellent: 15, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [DeActivate Portal User by himself using apex class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17841/deactivate-portal-user-by-himself-using-apex-class)

  **Net Score: 11** (Excellent: 11, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Email Template Replace merge field](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17849/email-template-replace-merge-field)

  **Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Help with question on trigger logic](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18000/help-with-question-on-trigger-logic)

  **Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Losing field level information](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16956/losing-field-level-information)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Is it possible to turn permissions on and off through API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17046/is-it-possible-to-turn-permissions-on-and-off-through-api)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 13, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Rich text Area Image ajax fetch as blob](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18032/rich-text-area-image-ajax-fetch-as-blob)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [What is the URL parameter for populating Cross object filters on reports?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17488/what-is-the-url-parameter-for-populating-cross-object-filters-on-reports)

  **Net Score: -7** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 10)

---

- [I wish to assign contacts, accounts to a particular business unit and time frame will be defined Is it possible?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17674/i-wish-to-assign-contacts-accounts-to-a-particular-business-unit-and-time-frame)

  **Net Score: -8** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 12)

---

Comment: Has the Site Self-Evaluation been removed? I can no longer see the queue

Answer (score 2):

More than any where there are lot of advanced Devs and advanced admins on this site and we get answers in flash and very accurate .Its been a great learning site for me and have been learning lot here .So thanks and waiting for this site to get in public GA .

There are some questions on this site of very high quality and we rarely see questions which are of low quality and that's nice of this site .

We have cool moderators and there are highly committed people on this community who have delivered excellent answers which are of great resource .

I am hoping after dreamforce  event this site will get more users and we will have more questions and solution's .Thank you stack exchange .